# Is there a Counterexamples in Category Theory book?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, book-recommendation

I know there are books called Counterexamples in Analysis and Counterexamples in Topology. I wonder, is there a book about counterexamples in category theory? It does not necessarily have to be called "Counterexamples in Category Theory", I am just wondering whether there is a book or at least a paper that talks about counterexamples in category theory.

Comment: I am unaware of there being a book. There is a page at ncatlab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/counterexamples+in+category+theory. Perhaps there will be a book one day.

Comment: One other counterexample that is not mentioned there in the nLab is that the naive image of a functor need not be a subcategory of the codomain in general (though it will be if the functor is injective on objects).